# How to load only what displayed in List, Grid,Gallery, etc...?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I would like to improve the load of my activities in my Android app.

Every activity is either a GridView, a List or a Gallery.

My questions is : How can I load only what's displayed ?

Let's say I have to display a list of 500 songs (The same with a grid of 500 pictures), and each cell includes the Thumbnail, title and lenght.

How can I know which one is currently displayed ?

I don't know if I made myself clear, if not please jut let me know.

Comment: So you want something that the email apps have, where as you scroll down it loads more items?

Comment: @James It can be ... sorry I don't have an android phone yet I still use the emulator, but I guess the email apps should do it. I know that in iPhone all the native application does that. They just loads the data that are currently displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [Lazy List Loading Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview).